# Enhance MS SQL Server performance on UNION operations

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query-optimization, union

I have a MS SQL Server table `T1` with three code columns: `CodeA`, `CodeB1` and `CodeB2`. And I have a table type variable with the same columns.

I must join the table variable with the `T1` table in order to get the lines in table variable that match for `CodeB1` and/or `CodeB2`, but not `CodeA`, or match `CodeA`, but neither `CodeB1` nor `CodeB2`.

I initially I did a single `SELECT` statement like that:

```
SELECT *
(SELECT 
 CASE WHEN t.CodeA = v.CodeA then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeA],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB1 = v.CodeB1 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB1],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB2 = v.CodeB2 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB2]
FROM @tableVariable v
INNER JOIN [T1] t
ON t.CodeA = v.CodeA or
   t.CodeB1 = v.CodeB1 or
   t.CodeB2 = v.CodeB2
)
WHERE NOT(EqualCodeA = 1 AND (EqualCodeB1 = 1 OR EqualCodeB2 = 1)
```

But that query has very poor performance. So I switched the `OR` in predicate for `UNION`, like that:

```
SELECT *
(SELECT 
 CASE WHEN t.CodeA = v.CodeA then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeA],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB1 = v.CodeB1 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB1],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB2 = v.CodeB2 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB2]
 FROM @tableVariable v
 INNER JOIN [T1] t
 ON t.CodeA = v.CodeA

 UNION
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN t.CodeA = v.CodeA then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeA],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB1 = v.CodeB1 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB1],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB2 = v.CodeB2 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB2]
 FROM @tableVariable v
 INNER JOIN [T1] t
 ON t.CodeB1 = v.CodeB1

 UNION
 SELECT 
 CASE WHEN t.CodeA = v.CodeA then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeA],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB1 = v.CodeB1 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB1],
 CASE WHEN t.CodeB2 = v.CodeB2 then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeB2]
 FROM @tableVariable v
 INNER JOIN [T1] t
 ON t.CodeB2 = v.CodeB2)
)
WHERE NOT(EqualCodeA = 1 AND (EqualCodeB1 = 1 OR EqualCodeB2 = 1)
```

The performance is now about ten times better, but it's still unacceptable. E.g. for 10K rows in table variable and 50K rows in `T1`, the query takes two minutes.

Looking at the actual execution plan, I see two `Hash Match (Union)` operations, each accounting for 46% of the cost.

How could I improve this performance?

**Note 1**: there is a Non-clustered index including all three columns, as well as three separate non-clustered indexes, one for each column.

**Note 2**: I use the `OPTION(RECOMPILE);` in order for the optimizer at least to know the table variable actual number of rows.

Comment: What does the execution plan show as using the most resources?

Comment: @TabAlleman the two "Hash Match (Union)" operations take 46% each

Comment: Not likely to make a huge difference but one case in each set could be removed. You don't need to do

    CASE WHEN t.CodeA = v.CodeA then 1 else 0 end as [EqualCodeA]
when the join is
    INNER JOIN [T1] t  ON t.CodeA = v.CodeA
you can do 
    1 as [EqualCodeA]

Comment: It's hard to recommend a different query because it's not clear what information you're trying to retrieve from where.  You're showing a result set with 3 columns. does that result set actually have meaning or are you trying to simplify the actual query?

Comment: @EvanSteinbrenner you're right, Evan. But it really doesn't make much difference.

Comment: @JamieD77 I am simplifying, Jamie. But even when I retrieve just those columns, the performance is poor.

Comment: You should try to use a temp. table instead of table variable. Table variables don't have statistics and therefore are almost always estimated to have 1 row. That can make a huge difference to the plan if you actually have 10k rows.

Comment: @JamesZ thank's for the advice, James. I actually use `OPTION(RECOMPILE);` in order for the optimizer at least to know the table variable actual number of rows. But I'll try to use temp table.

Comment: If you don't need to remove duplicates, you should also use `union all` instead of union, so there's no need for sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I don't really see how the example code matches the description of your requirement, but assuming the latter is correct, this is what I came up with:

```
-- in order to get the lines in table variable that match for CodeB1 and/or CodeB2, but not CodeA, 
-- or match CodeA, but neither CodeB1 nor CodeB2.
SELECT v.*
  FROM @tableVariable v
  JOIN T1 t
    ON (v.CodeA <> t.CodeA AND (v.CodeB1 = t.CodeB1 OR v.CodeB2 = t.CodeB2))
    OR (v.codeA = t.CodeA  AND v.CodeB1 <> t.CodeB1 AND v.codeB2 <> t.codeB2)


GO

-- convert OR into UNION
SELECT v.*
  FROM @tableVariable v
  JOIN T1 t
    ON (v.CodeA <> t.CodeA AND (v.CodeB1 = t.CodeB1 OR v.CodeB2 = t.CodeB2))

UNION

SELECT *
  FROM @tableVariable v
  JOIN T1 t
    ON (v.codeA = t.CodeA  AND v.CodeB1 <> t.CodeB1 AND v.codeB2 <> t.codeB2)


GO

-- further convert OR into UNION
SELECT v.*
  FROM @tableVariable v
  JOIN T1 t
    ON v.CodeA <> t.CodeA 
   AND v.CodeB2 = t.CodeB2

UNION

SELECT v.*
  FROM @tableVariable v
  JOIN T1 t
    ON v.CodeA <> t.CodeA 
   AND v.CodeB1 = t.CodeB1

UNION

SELECT v.*
  FROM @tableVariable v
  JOIN T1 t
    ON v.codeA = t.CodeA  
   AND v.CodeB1 <> t.CodeB1 
   AND v.codeB2 <> t.codeB2

-- potentially helpfull indexes
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON T1 (CodeA) INCLUDE (CodeB1, CodeB2)
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON T1 (CodeB1) INCLUDE (CodeA)
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON T1 (CodeB2) INCLUDE (CodeA)
```

It might well be this has the exact same cost as your solution, the optimizer might be able to (internally) convert them into the exact same *action*. It'd be interesting to see the query-plans and/or get a better idea about the data at hand.

PS: and as already mentioned elsewhere, try to avoid @tableVariables, #tempTables are much better when handling more than a few records. (you can put indexes, statistics etc... as needed)

Comment: @JamesZ As you both suggested, I tryed Temp tables instead of table variables, and I added index including the temp tables' columns. The performance is now very good! The query is taking less than a second! Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you need three separate non clustered indexes on T1 for this case. also, if the three sections are mutually exclusive, change to "union all" instead of "union".

Comment: unfortunately the sections are not mutually exclusive. And I already have three separate non-clustered indexes.